# rational elliptic curve: torsion subgroup defined over abelian extensions

Tags: arithmetic, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry, cyclotomic-fields

I'm thinking about a question, that is if *E* is a rational elliptic curve, *K* is a cyclotomic field, how can I find the minimal subfield of *K* such that the torsion subgroup over *K* can also be defined over this subfield? I have found some papers for classification of torsion subgroups over **Q**^ab, quadratic fields, I wonder if there is connection between them? Thanks a lot.